# Stepping down 12 V to 9 V with minimal waste of energy?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have a 12 volt gel cell battery that outputs 13.6 volts when fully charged. I wanted to use it to provide backup power to my modem and router (both of which are supposed to draw a maximum of 0.6 A at 9 volts). I've looked at circuits using LM7809 voltage regulators, but those still waste power.

Now my question is, is there a more efficient way to step down this 12 V source to 9 V for these devices. Or should I even worry about efficiency at this small a scale at all?

Comment: My advice would be to first check the modem and the router to see if they could run directly from the battery. Many such devices nowadays have switching power supplies that accept wide range of voltages and the adapter voltage just happens to be the most efficient voltage or the adapter model just happens to be the cheapest design available. Also for that amount of current, you'll definitely need a DC-DC converter to go from 12 V to 9 V. Remember that current times voltage is power, so a rough approximation give you 3 W that regulator would need to dissipate at  maximum load and that's a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @AndrejaKo but wouldn't I run the risk of frying the devices by directly connecting the battery to them, if they do not contain the switching power supply?

Comment: Here are the innards of my router: http://i662.photobucket.com/albums/uu347/erreterr/DSC02532.jpg

I cannot identify a voltage regulating component like an lm7805.

Comment: `Frying` is an overused term. Even if the device uses a linear regulator, it wouldn't just fry, it would overheat and then develop symptoms over time. This gives time for experimentation. In any case, I believe that your router has a switch-mode power supply. There are two capacitors and an inductor on the right side of the photo. Can you post a higher resolution image of the right part of the router? I'm interested in the area below the power switch, near the inductor and FCC/CE logos. It would be great if I could read the part numbers on the chips and capacitors, just to be 100% sure.

Comment: @Person09 the 8 pin ic just above the Caps and Torrid on the left side of the board, what does it say? 10 bucks says that's a switching voltage regulator ic.

Comment: I don't think the presence of a switched mode regulator (whatever its spec) is enough reason to assume the device can take a higher power supply voltage that the power adapter it came with. Start by looking at the type plate of the device and its documentation.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Here are a few pictures of the part you asked for. Let me know if these are OK. http://imgur.com/a/YXtnj

Comment: @Passerby That thing is a mp1482. Which upon googling shows that it's a switching regulator with an input maximum of 18 V! :D So, I guess that means I'm in the clear?

Comment: @Person09, the large caps, what voltage do they say on them?

Comment: @Passerby Sorry for the extremely belated response. The caps are 16 volts. I've been running both the modem and router at 14 volts for the past couple of weeks and they've been running smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

You say you need for "backup".

In this case you can use a MOSFET to switch the regulator. In this case you need a comparator circuit or microcontroller.

LM7809 has 5mA of quiescent current. A low power MCU like MSP430 and simple MOSFET will not draw more than that 5mA.

Comment: I don't really think it has to be that complicated, does it?

We've figured out that my router has a switching voltage regulator that accepts voltages up to 18 V. So wouldn't it be easier to just hook up the battery directly to the router and charge the battery with a small wall-wart type AC-DC 12 V adapter?

Comment: Well thats an option too. But in case of managed backup system and efficiency, an mcu to switch a mosfet is not really complicated I guess. And btw the battery type is important factor to direct connection to a voltage source. You wouldn't like to connect a lipo battery to directly a voltage source.

Answer (score 1):

It's a question whether you want to take the extra effort of using a switch mode converter. Linear regulators are easier to use, better in terms of EMC but come with the disadvantage of converting the voltage drop times the current into heat:
$$
0.6A \cdot (12V - 9V) = 1.8W
$$

So if using a linear converter you will have to add a proper heatsink. In my experience it would be sufficient to use a regulator in TO-3 package.

In case you use a switching regulator you can (in theory) do the conversion in a lossless fashion. In reality you get efficiencies greater than 80%, for example 84% for the 9V/666mA version this module:
http://www.tracopower.com/fileadmin/medien/dokumente/pdf/datasheets/tmr6wi.pdf

Comment: Thank you Simon. That regulator you linked to seems to be what I was looking for, but it would be a pain to source that where I live. I'll try connecting the battery directly to the router since it turns out, there is a switching voltage regulator (with a maximum of 18 V input) already present inside the router. If it overheats though, then I'll just have to make do with a linear regulator because around 4 watts of wastage is something I can live with.

Comment: I don't think you have to fear the internal DC-DC converter will overheat when it allows 18V.

Comment: Great! That's what I wanted to hear :)

I'll be connecting the router to the battery soon as I build an SLA battery charging circuit.